# What Datagrid event should I use for this?

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I have a datagridview which I called from a datasource.

http://i58.tinypic.com/dwvxxv.png

and here's the code for that:

```
        string strsql = "select a.Denomination, a.Value, b.Quantity, b.Amount from [Masterfile].[Denomination] a "+
        "left join [GEARS-POS].[POS].[CashCount] b "+
        "on A.Sequence = B.Sequence order by a.sequence";
        dataGridViewEx1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        DataTable dtgt = Library.Lib.GetData(strsql, Common.Common.ConnectionString());
        dataGridViewEx1.DataSource = dtgt.DefaultView;

        dataGridViewEx1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Denomination";
        dataGridViewEx1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Value";
        dataGridViewEx1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Quantity";
```

What I want is for every time I change one of cell from quantity row, then the Amount cell would change from where the column corresponds with.

I'm beginner with the event stuff so I really need help when it comes to this kind of things. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CellEndEdit event :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

   if(e.ColumnIndex == 2) // quantity column
   {
     int col = e.ColumnIndex;
     int row = e.RowIndex;
     int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value); // entered quantity
     double value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col -1].Value); // value of corresponding row

     dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col+1].Value = (quantity*value).ToString();
   }
}
```

**Further concerns**

The above code is so simple and assume no misuse with the software, the next one is a bit more solid:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] == null) return;
   // rest of code as in the upper one
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   int col = e.ColumnIndex;
   int row = e.RowIndex;
   string data = e.FormattedValue.ToString();

   if(!checkData(data))
   {
     e.Cancel = false;
     return;
   }

   // for example I want to limit the quantities to be between [0, 100]

   if(col == 2)
   {
     int iData = Convert.ToInt32(data);
     if(iData < 0 || iDat > 100)
     {
       e.Cancel = true;
       return;
     }
   }


}


private bool chackData(string d)
{
   if (d.Length <= 0 || d.Length >= 10) return false;

   foreach (char c in d)
   {
     if('0' >= c || c >= '9')
     {
        return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Surely `CellValueChanged` is more appropriate.  Who cares if an editing session just ended if the `Value` didn't change and what if the `Value` changes without a cell being edited directly?

Comment: You're still using `CellEndEdit` so it's still wrong in that regard.

Comment: `wrong in that regard`: I guess you mean the data entered by user vs data entered somehow else ? according to my understanding the OP intends to input the data + he said it works = don't think it is wrong in that regard, rather the *regard* itself might be wrong, you wanna check? ask the OP @jmcilhinney